# Spring Data JPA @PreUpdate not called when update using @Query from Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update a record from Spring JPA repository. Update method is using @Query annotation as shown below.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update Person u set u.status = :status where u.id = :id")
public int updateStatus(@Param("id") ID id, @Param("status") String status);
```

But when I call this method my entity's @PreUpdate method is not getting called.

Comment: That's normal and expected. The query is transformed to a SQL query and executed by the database. It doesn't modify the entities in memory. Why are you using such a query, instead of just doing `person.setStatus(status)`?

Comment: This query is to avoid 2 queries to update entity. Otherwise it will be 1 query to fetch the record @ other to update the entity.

Comment: @HemantS Have you found the solution of it?

Comment: `@PreUpdate` is a feature of the ORM tool (JPA). Writing `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries explicitly is bypassing the tool and the abstractions that makes `@PreUpdate` (and many other features) work. Either use the ORM approach (`PersonRepository#updatePerson(person)`) or be prepared to implement this feature yourself.